Find the minimum of $x^2 + y^2$ given $xy(x^2 - y^2) = x^2 + y^2, x \neq 0$

Find the minimum possible value of $x^2 + y^2$ given that $x$ and $y$ are
real numbers satisfying $xy(x^2 - y^2) = x^2 + y^2$ and $x \neq 0$. (Source: British mathematical olympiad 2006 round 2 Problem 1).

I have been stuck on this problem for a while, and any hints would be appreciated.
What I have so far:
Note that we can never have $y=0$, we can show this by contradiction, assume
that $y=0$ then substituting into our equation gives $0=x^2 \iff 0=x$ a contradiction since
$x \neq 0$. Then I tried applying AM-GM like so,
$xy(x^2 - y^2) = x^2 + y^2 \geq 2xy$
$x^2 - y^2 \geq 2$
however it didn't seem to yield anything useful.

Are you familiar with Lagrange multipliers?

No I am not familiar.

@md2perpe The problems at math Olympiads are usually solved without calculus.

Let $a := x^2 + y^2, b := xy$. Using
$(x^2 + y^2)^2 - (x^2 - y^2)^2 = 4(xy)^2$ and the condition, we have $b^2(a^2 - 4b^2) = a^2$ which results in
$$a = \frac{2b^2}{\sqrt{b^2 - 1}}
= 2\sqrt{b^2 - 1} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{b^2 - 1}}
\ge 4$$
with equality if $b^2 = 2$ (here we use AM-GM).
From $b^2 = 2$ and $a = 4$, we can solve $x, y$.
Thus, the minimum is $4$.

Can I ask how did you notice that $\frac{2b^2}{\sqrt{b^2 - 1}} = 2\sqrt{b^2 - 1} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{b^2 - 1}}$

@nathan I split $2b^2 = 2(b^2 - 1) + 2$.

I think a nice approach would be to use polar coordinates. Write $$x=r\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta$$
Then you want the minimum of $r^2$ given $$r^4\sin\theta\cos\theta(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)=r^2$$
Since $x\ne 0$, then $r\ne 0$, and you can divide by $r^2$.
You get $$r^2=\frac1{\sin\theta\cos\theta(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)}\\=\frac4{2\cdot(2\sin\theta\cos\theta)(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)}\\=\frac4{2\sin2\theta\cos2\theta}\\=\frac4{\sin4\theta}$$
The minimum value of $r^2$ happens when $\sin4\theta=1$, so $\min r^2=4$.

We have  $\displaystyle xy(x^2-y^2)=x^2+y^2$
$\displaystyle xy(x+y)(x-y)=x^2+y^2$
$\displaystyle (xy+y^2)(x^2-xy)=x^2+y^2$
$\displaystyle (xy+y^2)(x^2-xy)\leq \frac{1}{4}(xy+y^2+x^2-xy)^2$
$\displaystyle (x^2+y^2)\leq \frac{1}{4}(x^2+y^2)^2$
$\displaystyle \Longrightarrow (x^2+y^2)\geq 4$
(Above using $4ab\leq (a+b)^2$)

It is a nice one.
